# What Java type does the Oracle type RECORD map to?

Tags: oracle, grails, jdbc, sqldatatypes

I have a Grails application that is required to call an Oracle database package function.

The return value of the function is a `RECORD` Oracle data type.

What Java Oracle datatype does `RECORD` map to?

I have found [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm), however, I am either blind or it doesn't have the information I need.

Example code:

*Package type declaration*

```
TYPE subjectDuration IS RECORD (
  min_duration PLS_INTEGER,
  max_duration PLS_INTEGER
);
```

*Function*

```
FUNCTION getSubjectDuration(
  subject_code IN PACKGE.SUBJ_CODE%type,
  course_number IN PACKGE.CRSE_NUMB%type,
  term_code IN PACKGE.EFF_TERM%type
)
RETURN subjectDuration
IS
  record_rowid ROWID;
  subject_duration subjectDuration;
BEGIN
  ...
  /*function code */

  RETURN(subject_duration);
END;
```

*Grails code that calls the above function*

```
String packageCheck = "BEGIN packge.getSubjectDuration(:subjectCode, :courseNumber, :termCode); END; "

sql.call(packageCheck, [subjectCode: subjectCode, courseNumber: courseNumber, termCode: termCode],
    // OracleTypes.OTHER is the wrong type. I need the correct type for RECORD, which doesn't exist in OracleTypes.
    Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.OTHER)) { cursorResults ->         
    if (cursorResults.next()) {
        def result = cursorResults.getAt(0)
        log.debug(result)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution was as follows:

```
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleTypes
...
try {
    String packageCheck = "BEGIN csu.swrtcbs.getSubjectDuration(?, ?, ?, ?, ?); END; "

    sql.call(packageCheck, [subjectCode, courseNumber, termCode, Sql.out(OracleTypes.NUMBER), Sql.out(OracleTypes.NUMBER)]) { minDur, maxDur ->

        //log.debug("From Banner: Min duration: ${minDur}, Max duration: ${maxDur}")
        minDuration = (minDur == null) ? 1 : ((java.math.BigDecimal) minDur).toString()
        maxDuration = (maxDur == null) ? null : ((java.math.BigDecimal) maxDur).toString()
    }

    // Do something with the output: minDuration and maxDuration

} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error("Something failed.", e)
}
```

Where the output is specified in the `sql.call` as `Sql.out()` and specifying the OracleType.